# How can I know that all Futures are resolved in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, future

I have some parsing application and it basically do the following

- Adds `start()` method to the IOLoop as a callback to call on the next iteration
- `start()` calls another function, let's call it `get_input()`
- `get_input()` is a coroutine which fetches some data over the net, then schedules another coroutine, `process_input()`, by adding it as  `start()` was added in the first step.
- `get_input()` also checks some condition which depends on fetched data and may schedule itself with adjusted arguments

Now, after this condition renders `False` I know that there won't be any new input items to process. 
But how do I know that there are no Futures of `get_input()` and `process_input()` which are still unresolved?

I suppose this could be solved by implementing a kind of counter, which is incremented every time `process_input()` is called and decrementing after it is resolved
But if there is a chain of different coroutines? How can I track their state so that if I stop IOLoop, no tasks will die before they get resolved?

Maybe, there should be some kind of hierarchical counting...

*edit:*

2 @dano
OK, I see now... I was inattentive. You really do not block as its own call is inside this list
But!

1. Such organization reqires that only `yield` construction must be used, no `add_callback` as otherwise we lose "waiting" concept
2. The recursion level grows.. Mmm, dunno if it's too bad

What I came up with today is "metafuture"
I create a bare `Future()` object. 
I decorate every `@coroutine`-enabled method with my decorator, which increments counter field in "metafuture" and adds a custom done callback to their futures, that should decrement it.

When it reaches zero, "metafuture" resolves by calling `set_result(None)`
THere is also a IOLoop callback that yields exactly that metafuture:

```
    @coroutine
    def wait_for_complete(self):
      yield self._input_data_collected
      yield self._all_futures_resolved
      self.complete()
```

So after that we know no futures are pending. THat's a hard way like manually implementing refcounting but it covers `IOLoop.add_callback()` way of adding tasks as well

Comment: Do you always want to stop the IOLoop after you're done processing? Or is the request to stop the IOLoop out of band and you want it to wait until the work is done before it actually does the stopping?

Comment: @dano, as I understand, if I call `IOLoop.stop()` with some futures still unresolved, they won't be processed. So I assume that I should manually track the moment when all processing is done and then `stop()` it

Comment: That's true; `IOLoop.stop()` won't wait for outstanding work to finish. However, you its possible you can organize your application so that it automatically exits once it's done doing its work. It's hard to say without actually being able to see how your program is structured, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your methods so that they don't return until all the work is done, rather than scheduling callbacks. Then you could just call `IOLoop.run_sync(start)` and the call won't return until all the processing is complete:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

@gen.coroutine
def start():
    yield get_input()

@gen.coroutine
def get_input(*args, **kwargs):
    data = yield fetch_data_over_net()
    futs = []  # list of Future objects
    futs.append(process_input(data))
    if should_call_myself(data):
        futs.append(get_input(newargs, newkwargs))
    yield futs # This will wait for all Future objects in the list to complete.

@gen.coroutine
def process_input(data):
    # do stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    IOLoop.instance().run_sync(start)
```

We take advantage of the fact that coroutines return `Futures`, and that Tornado supports [waiting for multiple Futures in parallel](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#module-tornado.gen) so that we can run as much as possible concurrently, without actually ever returning from `get_input` (and therefore `start`) before all the dependent work is done.

Comment: I know this feature of Tornado, I actually use it in another place. However, if I used `yield [futures]`, execution of `get_input()` would block until they are done, which is impacting performance since I can run another `get_input()` right away - without waiting for process_input().
That's why I use `add_callback()` to schedule processing

Comment: @Ojomio How are you triggering `get_input()`, aside from calling it once inside `start()`, and recursively inside `get_input()` itself? I cover the recursive call in my example, and it isn't blocked by `process_input`; they run in parallel. It might be helpful if you add some sample code to your question which shows exactly what you're doing.

Comment: OK, I see now... I was inattentive. You really do not block as its own call is inside this list

Comment: Is `yield fetch_data_over_net()` a blocking call?

Comment: @user1045085 It will not block the IO loop, because it's a coroutine we are `yield`ing from, but it is "blocking" in the sense that the flow of execution will wait for it to finish before moving on to the next line.